# How to find out if property is inherited from a base class or declared in derived?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class that is derived from an abstract class. Getting a type of a derived class I want to find out which properties are inherited from abstract class and which were declared in  the derived class.

```
public abstract class BaseMsClass
{
    public string CommonParam { get; set; }
}

public class MsClass : BaseMsClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MsClass()
    { }
}

var msClass = new MsClass
{
    Id = "1122",
    Name = "Some name",
    CommonParam = "param of the base class"
};
```

So, I would like to quickly find out that CommonParam is an inherited parameter and Id, Name are params declared in MsClass. Any suggestions?

Attempt to use declared only flag returns me empty PropertyInfo array

```
Type type = msClass.GetType();
type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)

-->{System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0]}
```

However, GetProperties() returns all properties of inheritance hierarchy.

```
type.GetProperties()

-->{System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[3]}
-->[0]: {System.String Id}
-->[1]: {System.String Name}
-->[2]: {System.String CommonParam}
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can specify [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx)`(`[`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)`)` to get the properties that are defined in the derived class.  If you then call `GetProperties` on the base class, you can get the properties defined in the base class.

---

In order to fetch the public properties from your class, you could do:

```
var classType = typeof(MsClass);
var classProps = classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
var inheritedProps = classType.BaseType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Somehow this approach doesn't give an expected result. Question is updated.

Comment: @Maxim you need `type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)`. +1 to Reed, hope he will update answer a bit

Answer (score 16):

You can check based on the `DeclaringType` as below:

```
var pros = typeof(MsClass).GetProperties()
                          .Where(p => p.DeclaringType == typeof(MsClass));
```

To get properties from base class you can call similarly:

```
var pros = typeof(MsClass).GetProperties()
                          .Where(p => p.DeclaringType == typeof(BaseMsClass));
```

Answer (score 3):

This may helps:

```
Type type = typeof(MsClass);

Type baseType = type.BaseType;

var baseProperties = 
     type.GetProperties()
          .Where(input => baseType.GetProperties()
                                   .Any(i => i.Name == input.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 Definitely works, not very elegant though. Expected that something should be already implemented to support required request.