# Check if a "Type" override a dynamic type

Tags: c#, reflection

We are giving some repetitive jobs to a consultant company, we just have a few constraints that could not be checked by compilation, like a requirement to override a specific property in all class implementing a specific interface.

The property of the interface, which should be overrided in all classes has the following signature:

```
dynamic Definition{get;}
```

I found this stackoverflow question: [How to find out if property is inherited from a base class or declared in derived?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746854/how-to-find-out-if-property-is-inherited-from-a-base-class-or-declared-in-derive)

Which is closed to my case, but in my case, the property is defined is inherited class and overrided in this one:

```
public class ClassA:IMyInterface
{
   public virtual dynamic Definition{get{ /*return SomethingSpecificToClassA;*/}}
}

public class ClassB:ClassA
{
   public override dynamic Definition{get{ /*return SomethingSpecificToClassB;*/}}
}

//The end goal is to know if ClassB has correctly overriden the property
bool overriden = typeof(ClassB)GetProperties(...).Any(p=>p.Name=="Definition");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find for property declared only in your type of interests:

```
var prop = typeof (ClassB).GetProperty("Definition", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Then you can then check if its getter is virtual:

```
prop.GetMethod.IsVirtual
```

which will be `false` if `Definition` hides (or uses `new`) in `ClassB`

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution: you ask `ClassB` its interface map, you look for the method you want in the interface map and then you look where the implementation method (`classMethod`) is declared.

```
var interfaceMethod = typeof(I).GetProperty("Definition").GetGetMethod();
var map = typeof(ClassB).GetInterfaceMap(typeof(I));
var ix = Array.IndexOf(map.InterfaceMethods, interfaceMethod);
var classMethod = map.TargetMethods[ix];
bool isDeclaredInClass = classMethod.DeclaringType == typeof(ClassB);
```

Comment: You could check the MemberAttributes to if the override flag is set

Comment: Nice way of doing it( I slightly edited it : `typeof(ClassB).GetProperty("Definition").DeclaringType == typeof(ClassB)` in order to only know the current check class. Any way to make an additional check for the case you specify(  `new dynamic Definition`)

Comment: @Georg Where is this MemberAttributes you mention?

Comment: @Georg In a chain of three classes, with ClassA as written, ClassB with "new virtual" and ClassC with override on ClassB on you couldn't :-)

Comment: @J4N If you have a ClassB that overrides Definition and a ClassC that inherits ClassB without overriding Definition, I think it's Ok, because Definition will be overridden (for this reason I built the check in that way)

Comment: @xanatos : Yeah, but in my real case, I've 500+ classes, sometimes with 3-6 inheritance level(6 is rare) so when I get the class by reflection, I don't know which may be the parent. BUT, in some error I happen to made, I put a `new` instead of the expected `overrride` it works currently in the code the way we use it, but may not works in the future so I would like to be able to detect this too, possible?

Comment: @J4N added another solution based on the `GetBaseDefinition`

Comment: Yeah but like I said, I don't know the `typeof(ClassA)` in my real case, I just receive one type, I know that this class or one of its parent has implemented the interface, and I want to know if this specific class has overriden this property.

Comment: @J4N then use Konrad's solution. I didn't comprehend your prerequisites

Comment: @J4N sorry I confused the framework, with Reflection it is not as easy but as in the answer now, it is possible

Comment: @xanatos Yes but this is also true for your answer now, you would better check the GetBaseDefinition() chain until you found the original Definition getter.

Comment: @xanatos But with your new answer, you also have to know the type in which the property is really implemented?

Comment: @J4N changed everything... Now it should be what you asked: you want that the interface method is overridden in the "current" type

Comment: Yeah it seems to work, but it seems more complicate(and using more resource than the answer from Konrad). Any idea of something that you would cover with your solution and he doesn't?

Comment: @J4N this solution won't be fooled if there is a ClassB that uses new virtual and a ClassC that override the ClassB, because it checks that the method is the one declared in the interface

Comment: Ok I see, but in ma case, every class will be checked, so it means that I will get an error to correct the ClassB, and the ClassC will worked. But thank you very much anyway :)